# Hive external location access issue to Azure ADLS with Trino

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-storage, trino

I have a Trino instance running on a cluster with the need for Trino to connect to ADLS on Azure. For this I have a Hive metastore spinned up in the same cluster.
When I try to connect to the external ALDS container with the following query, I get the below error:

```
USE hive.default;
CREATE SCHEMA hive.web
WITH (location = 'abfs://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/')
```

```
SQL Error [33]: Query failed (#20221207_104043_00017_jhcwz): Invalid location URI: abfs://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/
```

The hive metastore is configured with the following data in the core-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net</name>
    <value><access_key></value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
    <value>4320</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: did you add hadoop-azure jars?

Comment: HI, please post a solution if this issue is solved, i also have same error.